# On page load, if URL hash matches one of the values in the array, scroll to the element with the matching data-load-id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following:

```
var scrollingAnchorIds = [];
    var getTheseIds = $(".anchor-content").each(function() {
        scrollingAnchorIds.push($(this).data('load-id'));
    });
    console.log(scrollingAnchorIds);

    $(window).bind("load", function() {
        if(document.URL.indexOf(scrollingAnchorIds[i]) >= 0){ 
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: elementWithMatchingDataLoadIdGoesHere.offset().top - 50},850);
        }
    });
```

I get the values of each data-load-id, add them to array.  Right now I'm stuck on checking when the pages loads, does the url contain that hash value, if so, scroll to the element with the matching value.

sample html of what element it would scroll to:

```
<div data-load-id="#83" class="anchor-content"></div>
<div data-load-id="#91" class="anchor-content"></div>
<div data-load-id="#99" class="anchor-content"></div>
```

Comment: Why include # in the attribute? You are also using `i`, but you have no `for-loop`. And why not wrap all of your code in `$(function(){ //Code })` instead of the `$(window).bind("load"...`

Comment: the # needed to be in the attribute as a request of the client, for the instance of 'i', that was me just trying the latest code I have.

Comment: Well, where do you define `i` and increment it? And loop? Please provide a fiddle and try to update your code some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When thinking about it, most of your code seems excessive. Try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("[data-load-id='" + window.location.hash + "']").offset().top - 50},850);
});
```

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/gc2qwj75/2/) also, though window.location.hash does not work in this.